# What does CATKIN_IGNORE file does in build folder in catkin_ws?

Tags: ros, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
While the ROS tutorials page on catkin_workspace, I  came across the CATKIN_IGNORE file present in the build folder contain in the catkin_ws. I want to know what does the CATKIN_IGNORE file do ?

Link- http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces#Source_Space

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254814/what-does-catkin_ignore-file-does-in-build-folder-in-catkin_ws-?/) by [a443](https://answers.ros.org/users/29219/a443/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2017-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`CATKIN_IGNORE` is a bit underdocumented, but the tutorial you link actually seems to contain the answer to your question:

> ```
> CATKIN_IGNORE         -- Keeps catkin from walking this directory
> ```

In other words: a `CATKIN_IGNORE` file in the `build` directory makes Catkin (ie: `catkin_make`, `catkin_make_isolated`, but also `catkin` from `catkin_tools`) ignore that specific directory.

This works for other directories as well.

Related REP: [REP-128: Naming Conventions for Catkin Based Workspaces](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0128.html).

Related ROS Answers question: #q208180.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [a443](https://answers.ros.org/users/29219/a443/) on 2017-02-16**:
Thanks gvdhoorn

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2017-07-07**:
REP-128 shows this file in a workspace `build/` dir (and with multiple pkgs shown in `workspace_folder/src` I took it to imply a meta-package or even `~/catkin_ws` itself). I only got it to work in the top level of the package. In that sense, I found the existing documentation confusing.

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2017-07-07**:
[This answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/208180/how-to-use-catkin_ignore-file-correctly/) resolved my confusion on what to do after trying a bunch of incantations of it in a `catkin_ws/src/pkg/build` location. Ultimately I just used `~/catkin_ws/src/pkg/CATKIN_IGNORE` successfully.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-07**:
As I wrote: `CATKIN_IGNORE` is rather underdocumented. But from your issue on `catkin_pkg` I'm guessing this is sort-of resolved now.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-07**:
The question & answer you link to are the same as I linked to as being 'related'?